# Multi Lenguaje con Laravel 7: Problema la mostrar URL

Tags: php, laravel

Mi aplicación selecciona correctamente el lenguaje de manera automática y también seleccionándole de forma manual, pero necesito mostrar la URL según el idioma en el que estoy: Ej: dominio.es/es/

Creo un middleware con el siguiente código:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Localization
{

    //Multilanguage Middleware
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
       if(\Session::has('locale'))
       {
           \App::setlocale(\Session::get('locale'));
       }
       return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Lo añado correctamente al Kernel, y posteriormente añado esto a mis rutas:

```
//LANGUAGE
Route::get('locale/{locale}', function ($locale){
    Session::put('locale', $locale);

    if (request()->fullUrl() === redirect()->back()->getTargetUrl()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return redirect()->back();
});

//WEB
    Route::view('/', 'home')->name('home');
```

Todo funciona correctamente, pero no sé como hacer para que en mi ruta se vea /es/